# How to take value outside from the method?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I used the following currency format pipe method

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'currencyFormat'
 })
export class CurrencyFormat {
  constructor() { }
  transform(value: number,
            currencySign :'$',
            decimalLength: number = 2,
            chunkDelimiter: string = ',',
            decimalDelimiter: string = '.',
            chunkLength: number = 3
           ): 
  string {
         let result = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + chunkLength + '})+' + (decimalLength > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')';
         let num = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~decimalLength));
         return (decimalDelimiter ? num.replace('.', decimalDelimiter) : num).replace(new RegExp(result, 'g'), '$&' + chunkDelimiter) + currencySign;
       }
 }
```

But I have to assign the currency sign from another service named "contextService". Which means below

```
this.contextService.company.subscribe(param => {
    this.currencySymbol = param.currencyCode.toString();
  })
```

Now the the currencyCode is saved in the variable "**currencySymbol**".

Instead of giving the currency symbol directly, I have to assign the above method in **currencySign**

I tried to assign like

```
  transform(value: number,
     currencySign = this.contextService.company.subscribe(param => {
             this.currencySymbol = param.currencyCode.toString();
            }),
     decimalLength: number = 2,
     chunkDelimiter: string = ',',
     decimalDelimiter: string = '.',
     chunkLength: number = 3
   }
```

Above method is not working. When I console I got it as [object,object]

How I solve this?? Is there any other method save the value in **currencySign**??

Comment: Are you talking about a pipe parameter? https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe you can simply insert the currencySymbol to the pipe: `| currencyFormat:currencySymbol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new property `currencySign` inside the `CurrencyFormat` pipe. Inject ContextService to CurrencyFormat pipe and subscribe to the company property from the constructor. This will keep the `currencySign` property always updated. Then you can directly use it without passing it as a parameter to `transform` method.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'currencyFormat'
})
export class CurrencyFormat {

  currencySign = '$';

  constructor(private contextService: ContextService) {
    this.contextService.company.subscribe(param => {
      this.currencySign = param.currencyCode.toString();
    })
  }

  transform(value: number,
    decimalLength: number = 2,
    chunkDelimiter: string = ',',
    decimalDelimiter: string = '.',
    chunkLength: number = 3
  ): string {
    let result = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + chunkLength + '})+' + (decimalLength > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')';
    let num = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~decimalLength));
    return (decimalDelimiter ? num.replace('.', decimalDelimiter) : num).replace(new RegExp(result, 'g'), '$&' + chunkDelimiter) + this.currencySign;
  }
}
```

Now we have **$** as the default currency. It will be updated with currency from the `ContextService` whenever there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

the data you receive from the server is on object type.please convert it to string prior to processing.

```
  transform(value: number,
     currencySign = this.contextService.company.subscribe(param => {
             let convertedParam  = JSON.stringify(param);
             this.currencySymbol = convertedParam.currencyCode;
            }),
```